# KDE Plasma black screen and cursor after suspend/screen timeout

Tags: suspend, kde, 18.10

I have Kubuntu 18.10 installed on my PC and I noticed that there are times that after waking up the system from suspend I get a black screen and the mouse cursor and nothing else. I tried to figure out what is going on and I noticed that this may happen as well when the screen goes after X minutes and I move the cursor to turn it back on. First I thought that it was a GPU driver problem, but after several reinstallations of nVidia drivers (410/415) I managed to do nothing. I also read somewhere that a corrupted `~/.config` folder may be the case to cause such issues, but after deleting it and restarting the system the problem still persists. I have a GTX1060 (6GB) if that matters. If you need to post any log files or the output of a command(s) please do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after installing a bad widget (or "plasmoid", whatever that is?).

Just switch to another virtual terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F6</kbd>, for example to use virtual terminal 6 (or 5 if 0-indexed.)

Then run kpackagetool5 for KDE Plasma 5 to see your installed widgets

```
kpackagetool5 -l -t Plasma/Applet
```

It will yield a list of anything you have installed and most importantly, where they are on your system. This should be in your user directory `~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids`. Just move them out of there and restart Plasma to see if that fixes it for you. In my case, this amounted to doing

```
mkdir ~/plasmoids
mv ~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/* ~/plasmoids
systemctl restart lightdm
```

---

It is also possible to use `kpackagetool5` but I avoid using tools that have versions in their name out of principle.

```
kpackagetool5 -t Plasma/Applet --remove nameofwidget
```